# System.IO.Compression is missing in self-contained builds on .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net

For some reason, when I try to run my MonoGame project built as self-contained on .NET 6 and encounter usage of **ZipFile** class, it throw the following exception:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Compression, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

The same code works perfectly fine in framework-dependent builds. I have tried disabling publishing as a single file and assembly trimming, it didn't fix the issue. Also tried installing **System.IO.Compression** from nuget, same results. What could be causing this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you tried creating a minimal reproduction? Does the same issue occur with a console app or a new MonoGame project?

Comment: I also facing the same problem when building console app with compression library as self-contained exe.
Including (.dll) file directly from bin folder also still error/not working.
@instrex have you found the solution?

Comment: Hey @ZemmyIndrapatih, it was a dumb mistake on my end caused by moving the currently running app file during auto update procedure before compression assembly could be loaded. Fixed it by calling `Assembly.Load("System.IO.Compression")` before doing any moving.